# Get data marked by user Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to get the value selected by the user. My only example is what Google Translation Extension do :

[image: example with Google translation]

I don't find another post on this, so I ask here, how can I do this.

Answer (score 0):

After searching and a lot of test, the solution is to use :

```js
window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).toString()
```